# Constructor for a packagetarget struct

Tags: c, error-handling, memory-management, constructor

As many of you know `goto` is usually signs of code smell. However I thought this could be an appropriate case, and would like confirmation or criticism.

Unnecessary section such as the called functions were removed. Every non-standard function returns an `int` as status, `0` is "OK"; except `linkedlist_open()` which returns a pointer which could be `NULL` if the system runs out of memory.

`packagetarget_close()` does implement the necessary `NULL` checks.

```c
packagetarget *packagetarget_open()
{
    packagetarget *target = (packagetarget*) malloc(sizeof(packagetarget));

    if (!target) return NULL;

    if (packagetarget_setname(target, ""))
        goto disposer;
    if (packagetarget_setsys(target, PACKAGETARGET_SYS))
        goto disposer;
    if (packagetarget_setarch(target, PACKAGETARGET_ARCH))
        goto disposer;
    if (packagetarget_setmin(target, PACKAGETARGET_MIN))
        goto disposer;
    if (packagetarget_setver(target, PACKAGETARGET_VER))
        goto disposer;
    if (packagetarget_setmax(target, PACKAGETARGET_MAX))
        goto disposer;

    linkedlist *comp = linkedlist_open();

    if (!comp) goto disposer;

    target->comp = comp;

    return target;   

    disposer:
        packagetarget_close(target);
        return NULL;
}
```

Each setter function follows a simple pattern. Since each setter is identical, I will only put the code for `packagetarget_setname`.

```c
int packagetarget_setname(packagetarget *target, char *name)
{
    if (!target) return 1;

    if (!name) return 2;

    target->name = realloc(target->name, strlen(name) * sizeof(char));

    if (!target->name) return 3;

    strcpy(target->name, name);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the `packagetarget_close` function:

```c
void packagetarget_close(packagetarget *target)
{
    if (!target) return;

    if (target->name) free(target->name);
    if (target->sys) free(target->sys);
    if (target->arch) free(target->arch);
    if (target->min) free(target->min);
    if (target->ver) free(target->ver);
    if (target->min) free(target->min);
    if (target->comp) linkedlist_close(target->comp);

    free(target);

    return;
}
```

`linkedlist_open` is a similar function to the `packagetarget_open`.

```
linkedlist *linkedlist_open()
{
    linkedlist *list = (linkedlist*) malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));

    if (!list) return NULL;

    list->head = NULL;
    list->length = 0;
    list->remhook = NULL;

    return list;
}
```

The one thing most of these functions is they may fail when the system runs out of memory. So I have implemented checks for each step.

Comment: "However I thought this could be an appropriate case, and would like confirmation or criticism." Yet you've stripped the code out of all it's context so we can't determine whether you're right or not. The code you've provided looks like it should've been used in a wrapper, not with `goto` constructs. Please provide more code and an explanation of what it's supposed to do so we can see how this snippet is being used. Stack Overflow likes minimal examples, Code Review does absolutely not. Please take a look at our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: Not all of the functions are written, yet. This function is a constructor for a struct named `packagetarget`. The idea is to allocate the struct in memory, and then call the setter methods for each field, which may fail. EDIT: If any step fails, the destructor function is called, once; and the function returns a null pointer.

Comment: If not all the functions are written, are you sure it works the way it should? And how can you be sure this is the right way to do it if you haven't completed the rest? It sounds like you're simply too early in the process got get this meaningfully reviewed and your question answered.

Comment: I have updated the question to include more code.

Comment: What is a constructor in C? I know what a constructor is in C++. Did you mean C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### packagetarget_close()

First of all, you have a **copy-and-paste error** in `packagetarget_close()`, where you attempt to free `target->min` twice, but not `target->max`.

Next, note that most of the `if` statements are superfluous.  As per the [standard behaviour for `free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free),

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the function does nothing.

## packagetarget_open()

You have **undefined behaviour** due to the way your error-handling works.  The chunk of memory returned by `malloc()` contains arbitrary junk.  If `packagetarget *target = (packagetarget*) malloc(sizeof(packagetarget))` succeeds, but one of the setters fails, then you would call `packagetarget_close()`, which would then interpret that arbitrary junk as pointers to memory to be freed.  A good way to fix that is to zero the memory before calling any of the setters.  You can either use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, or `memset()`, or a [struct initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11152160/1157100).

### Avoiding malloc()

In C, I prefer the init-cleanup idiom over new-destroy (which you call open-close).  In the init-cleanup idiom, the caller is responsible for providing the chunk of memory to be initialized, which gives the caller the option of providing either stack-based or heap-based memory.

### Avoiding goto

While indiscriminate use of `goto` leads to spaghetti code, there are [some circumstances where `goto` is justifiable, if used in a readily recognizable pattern](https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/1/12/151).

I think that your use of `goto` isn't horrible, but personally I would prefer to write the `if` statements as a chain of `&&` expressions.

### Suggested solution

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct packagetarget {
    char *name;
    char *sys;
    char *arch;
    char *min;
    char *ver;
    char *max;
    linkedlist comp;
} packagetarget;

int packagetarget_setname(packagetarget *target, const char *name) {
    if (!target) return 1;
    if (!name) return 2;
    target->name = realloc(target->name, strlen(name) * sizeof(char));
    if (!target->name) return 3;
    strcpy(target->name, name);
    return 0;
}

int packagetarget_setsys(packagetarget *target, const char *sys) {
    …
}

int packagetarget_setarch(packagetarget *target, const char *arch) {
    …
}

int packagetarget_setmin(packagetarget *target, const char *min) {
    …
}

int packagetarget_setver(packagetarget *target, const char *ver) {
    …
}

int packagetarget_setmax(packagetarget *target, const char *max) {
    …
}

packagetarget *packagetarget_cleanup(packagetarget *target) {
    if (target) {
        free(target->name);
        free(target->sys);
        free(target->arch);
        free(target->min);
        free(target->ver);
        free(target->max);
        linkedlist_cleanup(&target->comp);
    }
    return target;
}

packagetarget *packagetarget_init(packagetarget *target) {
    static const packagetarget empty = {};
    if (target) {
        *target = empty;
        if (!(0 == packagetarget_setname(target, "") &&
              0 == packagetarget_setsys(target, PACKAGETARGET_SYS) &&
              0 == packagetarget_setarch(target, PACKAGETARGET_ARCH) &&
              0 == packagetarget_setmin(target, PACKAGETARGET_MIN) &&
              0 == packagetarget_setver(target, PACKAGETARGET_VER) &&
              0 == packagetarget_setmax(target, PACKAGETARGET_MAX) &&
              linkedlist_init(&target->comp))) {
            packagetarget_cleanup(target);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return target;
}

int main() {
    packagetarget t;
    if (packagetarget_init(&t)) {
        …
    }
    packagetarget_cleanup(&t);
}
```

Comment: I did find the undefined behavior in `packagetarget_close()` myself too, but it was very late so I couldn't edit the question to fix it. Since I am very early in the project I may switch over idioms like you suggested because it made more sense. I used the open/close idioms because the only c api I am familiar with was Lua, which has the same structure. Also, marked as answer.